# Julia - ccall with pointer to function

Tags: pointers, callback, glut, julia, freeglut

I want to use glut with my Julia code and call it with ccall, I know how to call the most functions, but what do I have to do if there is a callback, for example I have the following function I want to call, how does my ccall has to look like:

```
FGAPI void    FGAPIENTRY glutKeyboardUpFunc( void (* callback)( unsigned char, int, int ) );
```

Could anyone give me an example how my ccall has to look like?

Comment: See http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#passing-julia-callback-functions-to-c and http://julialang.org/blog/2013/05/callback/